# Find id that are not present in DB

Tags: mongodb

Following query gives me in return objects that are present in DB and matches one of the ids in the list :

```
db.intervention.find( { _id: { $in: [ ObjectId("5f7fc2c3e21da01ffe711e48"), ObjectId("5f7fc255555da01ffe711e48") ] } } )
```

What I need is the contrary : to pass a list of ids, and get in response a list of ids that could not be found in DB.

Example :
In DB I have ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

Query :

```
db.intervention.find( { _id: { $something: ["D", "E", "F", "G"] } })
```

What I want in response is ["F", "G"] -> id that are in the list (in the query) but not in DB.

I'm new to Mongo and have no idea about how to achieve that.

Many Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job. But you'll have to supply the Array of Ids 2 times in the query.
Suppose you have ids. [84, 75, 76, 70, 71, 50, 12]. And Database don't have 50 & 12 in Database. Then..

```
db.intervention.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: {$in: [84, 75, 76, 70, 71, 50, 12]}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            foundIds: {$push: "$_id"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            notFoundIds: {$setDifference: [ [84, 75, 76, 70, 71, 50, 12], "$foundIds"]}
        }
    }

])
```

This will result:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "notFoundIds" : [
        50,
        12
    ]
}
```

Comment: Happy to hear that. :)